# Changing the arguments to Open() using python Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to change the arguments to open() so that my test code will open the files in the test/ directory instead of the original one.

file.py

```
def testing_opening():
    f = open( 'file', 'r' )
    return f.read()
```

Now, in my test file, I want to read files from 'test/file'.

How do I do that?
I can mock patch open(), but I don't know how to change it's arguments.

Please help

EDIT:
test_file.py

```
@patch( '__builtin__.open', new_callable=mock_open )
def test_open( m_file ):
    m_file.side_effect = open( os.curdir + '/test/'+ m_file.call_args[0][0], m_file.call_args[1] )
    f = testing_opening()
    print f
```

Comment: Can you add the mocking code to the question? That way we can help you modify it.

Comment: added sample test file.